# Finding Apps that do not appear in Macbook dock

Tags: applications

I recently got a macbook pro. Shouldn't programs like iMovie and GarageBand appear in the dock? When I search for them, I cannot find them. When I go to the App Store to download them, it tell me that they are already downloaded. Where can I open these applications?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to click the magnifying glass in the upper right corner (Spotlight), and type the name of the application you're looking for.  Once the application is running, you can add it to the dock permanently by pressing <kbd>control</kbd> and clicking the trackpad over the application's icon, then selecting the **Options** and finally, the **Keep in Dock** option.

Answer (score 0):

**Apps reside in /Applications**, available from the Finder sidebar. The Dock only shows applications which are default apps, installed by an installer that places the shortcut there (e.g. iWork '09) or that you place there yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find your Applications in Launchpad. The default gesture to get to Launchpad is to draw all 5 fingers from splayed to together on the trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

Applications are not added to the dock as standard. If you want to find your apps, loca the launchpad icon in the dock.

[image: launhcpad icon]

And this will display your apps in an iPad style layout which you can page back and forth within.

[image: app listing]

You can drag the app from here to the dock if it as an app you use a lot.

You can always search via spotlight. Click the magnifying glass in the main menu at the top of your desktop and type the name of the app you are looking for.